# Turtlebot rotates and sways like mad with Ros# on Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, ros, robotics

I was trying to move Turtlebot in Unity3D following the tutorial: https://github.com/siemens/ros-sharp/wiki/User_App_ROS_UnitySimulationExample.

All steps suggested by the tutorial and its video were done and double checked. The only difference was that I was running both ROS and Unity on a Linux device (Ubuntu 16.08). However, Unity could connect to localhost just fine and rviz could pick up the image published by Unity. So I do not think this should be the problem.

After launching the Ros node and starting simulation in Unity, the turtlebot just started to sway like a drunk:

[image]

I feel like this might be an Unity issue. Does anyone had similar problems before? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following:
https://github.com/siemens/ros-sharp/issues/333

As it states, if you Enable the "IsKinetic" option for your ROSConnector, turtlebot works as expected.